# PostgreSQL select columns based on case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM users;
```

Now I want to add a case statement with the following clauses:

```
 1. If 1+1 == 2 then show only id column
 2. If 1+2 == 2 then show only first_name column
 3. If 1+3 == 3 then show only last_name column
```

This is only stupid example but should describe what I'm looking for. Is there a way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: have you tried `CASE`?

Comment: postgresql.org has documentations on postgresql. Take a look at the documentations for conditional expressions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cond1 THEN id:TEXT
            WHEN cond2 THEN first_name::TEXT
            WHEN cond3 THEN last_name::TEXT
            ELSE 'some_default_value'
       END
FROM your_table;
```